# Pure javascript HTML parser for use in a BigQuery UDF

Tags: javascript, parsing, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions

I'm looking for a pure-javascript non-browser dependent HTML parser. Bonus if it supports finding elements by XPATH or CSS selectors. I want to use this in a BigQuery UDF so I can wrangle HTML fields in my data, but the problem is that many of these libraries (understandably) make calls into browser APIs to do the heavy lifting. For a BQ UDF, there is no browser. I need it to all happen in the JS.

Comment: Take a look here: https://johnresig.com/blog/pure-javascript-html-parser/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After taking a look at @GUNNM 's suggestion, I got something working fairly easily using the library:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION parseHTML(html STRING)
      RETURNS STRING
      LANGUAGE js
      OPTIONS (
        library=["gs://my-bq-udf/htmlparser.js"]
      )
      AS
    """
    captions = []
    elementSelected = false
    HTMLParser(html, {
      start: function( tag, attrs, unary ) {
        if (tag == "div") {
          for (var i = 0; i < attrs.length; i++) {
             if (attrs[i].name == "class" && attrs[i].value.indexOf("caption") > -1) {
                elementSelected = true
                return
             }
          }
        }
      },
      end: function( tag ) { 
        elementSelected = false
      },
      chars: function( text ) {  
        if (elementSelected) {
          captions.push(text)
        }
      },
      comment: function( text ) {  }
    });
    return captions.join("|")
"""
```

This is a simplified example but it shows how you can load this as an external UDF and using the callbacks, access and different parts of the structured HTML. I'm building an array of divs with class == "caption".

Thanks!